# 'RandomForestClassifier' object has no attribute 'oob_score_ in python

Tags: python, scikit-learn, random-forest

I am getting:

`AttributeError: 'RandomForestClassifier' object has no attribute 'oob_score_'.`
But I can see the attribute `oob_score_` in `sklearn` random forest classifier documentation.

```
param = [10,15,20,25,30, 40]  
# empty list that will hold cv scores
cv_scores = []
# perform 10-fold cross validation
for i in tqdm(param):
    clf = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators = i, max_depth = None,bootstrap = True, oob_score = True)
    scores = clf.oob_score_
    cv_scores.append(scores)
```

**ERROR**

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-37-d6c9c54f299e> in <module>()
     15 for i in tqdm(param):
     16     clf = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators = i, max_depth = None,bootstrap = True, oob_score = True)
---> 17     scores = clf.oob_score_
     18     cv_scores.append(scores)
     19 

AttributeError: 'RandomForestClassifier' object has no attribute 'oob_score_'
```

Comment: You have not used `fit` method. How can it return `oob_score_`?

Comment: Thanks! It worked.. oob_score_ is for Generalization accuracy but wat if i want to check the performance metric other than accuracy on cross validation data?

Comment: @HarikaM Depends on your task. Choose that metric which best describes the output of your task.

Answer (score 2):

[This kaggle](https://www.kaggle.com/raviolli77/random-forest-in-python) guide explains Random Forest.

Setting `warm_start` to `True` might give you a solution to your problem. The default value is `False`.