# 'PCA' object has no attribute 'explained_variance_'

Tags: scikit-learn, pca, dimensionality-reduction

Elbow Method - Finding the number of components required to preserve maximum variance.

My code:

```
pca = decomposition.PCA()

vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(min_df=10)
preprocessed_essay_tfidf = vectorizer.fit_transform(preprocessed_essay)
pca_data = preprocessed_essay_tfidf
pca.n_components = 3000

percentage_var_explained = pca.explained_variance_ / np.sum(pca.explained_variance_);
cum_var_explained = np.cumsum(percentage_var_explained)
```

I get the attribute error:

```
AttributeError: 'PCA' object has no attribute 'explained_variance_
```

Why is this?

I can find `explained_variance_` present [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.PCA.html).

Comment: You need to `fit` the model first.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ['RandomForestClassifier' object has no attribute 'oob\_score\_ in python](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/37509/randomforestclassifier-object-has-no-attribute-oob-score-in-python)

Comment: Fitting the model worked.Thanks.

Comment: If anyone is confused like I was, notice the property has an `_` at the end which I missed.

Answer (score 1):

PCA is an estimator and by that you need to call the `fit()` method in order to calculate the principal components and all the statistics related to them, such as the variances of the projections en hence the explained_variance_ratio.
`pca.fit(preprocessed_essay_tfidf)` or `pca.fit_transform(preprocessed_essay_tfidf)`