# 'RandomizedSearchCV' object has no attribute 'best_estimator_'

Tags: xgboost, machine-learning-model

```
from sklearn.model_selection import RandomizedSearchCV,GridSearchCV
import xgboost

classifier=xgboost.XGBClassifier()
random_search=RandomizedSearchCV(classifier,param_distributions=params,n_iter=5,scoring='roc_auc',n_jobs=-1,cv=5,verbose=3)
random_search.best_estimator_
```

> .**AttributeError: 'RandomizedSearchCV' object has no attribute 'best_estimator_'**

Comment: Does this answer your question? ['RandomForestClassifier' object has no attribute 'oob\_score\_ in python](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/37509/randomforestclassifier-object-has-no-attribute-oob-score-in-python)

Answer (score 3):

You have to fit the RandomizedSearchCV first in order to access this attribute.

```
random_search.fit(X_train, y_train)
print(random_search.best_estimator_)
```